Existence of a Basis for a 4-Dimensional Vector Space Given Two Linearly Independent Simple 2-Forms
Let $V$ be a 4-dimensional real vector space, and let $\sigma, \tau \in \bigwedge^2 V$ be linearly independent, simple 2-forms such that $\sigma \wedge \tau = 0$.
How can I show that there exists a basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ of $V$ such that
$$
\sigma = e^1 \wedge e^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \tau = e^1 \wedge e^3?
$$
Thank you for any insights or guidance on how to approach this proof.

The forms $\sigma$ and $\tau$ correspond to 2D subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$. Either the two subspaces intersect or they don't. In either case you can create a basis for $\Bbb R^4$ to either get the desired result or a contradiction.
